# How can I merge SVN branches into my trunk without losing commit messages and author details

Tags: svn, version-control

Our SVN repository works as follows:

- Nothing can be committed to the trunk unless it passes QA (Trunk always "releasable")
- Development work is done on branches which last approximately 30 days and are then reintegrated into the Trunk (after QA of course)

The problem with this approach is that all commits to the branches by all developers end up looking like a single huge commit on the Trunk by a single developer (the one who did the merge).

My question is:

Is there any way to improve this?  Do other version control systems do a better job at maintaining the logs?  Which ones?

I'm not interested in having everyone commit to the Trunk and branching for each release.  We did this for a number of years and it doesn't work for us.  We need to maintain concurrent development branches and need to have the ability to release on short notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With merge tracking (as of Subversion 1.5) you can see the revisions that produced the code that is later merged. See http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html#tsvn-dug-showlog-mergetrack
It describes exactly your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  The most polite RTFM I've ever received!

Comment: Wasn't meant to be one. But there's a nice screenshot and a description I could never put in better words.

Answer (score 1):

The logs aren't lost. Make sure to include merge information in the logs, for example with TortoiseSVN choose "Get merge logs" from the context menu:

[image: TortoiseSVN explorer sub menu]